# No sé cómo eliminar el texto "Haz clic para ver el comando" en bot discord

Tags: python, discord.py

Tengo un código creado en python y tengo un pequeño problema, se muestra el texto "*Haz clic para ver el comando*" y no sé como quitarlo:

Aquí hay una foto de lo que quiero decir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que quiero que me muestre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo los embeds en uno, espero haberme explicado bien

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
for d in data['data']:
         url = f"https://furniload.com/furni/" + d["code"] + ".png"
         img1 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))
         with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
             img1.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
             image_binary.seek(0)
             embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Hola que tal",description=f"[Descargar SWF ](https://images.habbo.com/dcr/hof_furni/"+d["revision"] +"/"+ d["code"]+ ".swf)", color=discord.Colour.random())
             embed.set_footer(text=d["code"], icon_url=f"https://images.habbo.com/dcr/hof_furni/"+d["revision"] +"/"+ d["code"]+ "_icon.png")
             embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://furni.png")
             await ctx.send(embed=embed,file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='furni.png'))
    except UnboundLocalError:
        url=""
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y mejora la indentacion del bloque de codigo! Revisa la guía de [ask].

Comment: Al final del bucle **NO** envíes el embed. Almacénalos en una lista y, una vez finalizado el bucle, envía un único mensaje con todos los embeds usando el parámetro `embeds` en vez de `embed`. Tienes un ejemplo en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/592687/306873). PD: Ten en cuenta que solo se pueden mandar 10 embeds en un mismo mensaje.