# ¿Cómo insertar múltiples embeds en el mismo comando? en python

Tags: python, discord.py

Necesito ayuda con las incrustaciones de Discord y tengo un pequeño problema.

Estoy tratando de crear varias incrustaciones al mismo tiempo con un solo comando

pero no puedo averiguar cómo hacerlo

Este es el código que estoy usando actualmente:

```
@bot.command()
async def habbo(ctx, *, habbo):



    
    urlhabbo = requests.get(f"https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users?name={habbo}")
    placashabbo = urlhabbo.json()
    placas = placashabbo["selectedBadges"]

    contar=0
    content=""


    
    for i in placas:
     contar=contar+1
     i = i['code']
     content = content + f"\n{i}\n"
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"l", description=f"{content}", color=discord.Colour.random())
    
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Necesito crear varias incrustaciones separadas con el mismo comando

Por ejemplo:

[image]

Alguien podría ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al usar [Context.send()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20context#discord.ext.commands.Context.send), en vez de utilizar el parámetro `embed`, utiliza el parámetro `embeds`:

> embeds (List[Embed]) – A list of embeds to upload. Must be a maximum of 10. (New in version 2.0.)

Debes crear los embeds uno por uno y añadirlos a una lista. Luego enviar la lista haciendo uso del parámetro `embeds`.

Código:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from typing import List

@bot.command(name='habbo')
async def habbo(ctx : commands.Context):

    embeds : List[discord.Embed] = []

    for i in range(5):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Código: ...',
            description=i,
            color=discord.Colour.random()
        )
        embeds.append(embed)

    await ctx.send(embeds=embeds)
```

Resultado:

[image: Imagen resultado]

Comment: ah. esque este bot lo hace de golpe: 
https://i.imgur.com/piUQJzf.gif

Comment: @paulita en el código que puse se mandan todos los embeds a la vez, si es a lo que te refieres. Si no, dímelo y te intento ayudar